# Incorrect code execution (extra text) Discord.py

Tags: python, string, discord, generator

Something incomprehensible when the code is executed, I don't know how to describe it, but the screenshot shows

Code:

```
symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('Код'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6))
```

Here you can see that the last 6 characters still change, but I do not understand how to remove unnecessary

[image]

Comment: @Tomerikoo. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6)` is a generator object: it gets evaluated lazily when you iterate over it.

`(random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6))` is a generator too. The parentheses are required if you want to use it in an argument list or similar.

`[random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6)]` is a list.

`list(random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6))` is too.

`tuple(random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6))` is a tuple.

`{random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6)}` is a set.

If you want a string, you need to join the chosen characters into one:

`''.join(random.choice(symbols) for x in range(6))`